# Option clash for package fontspec. \usepackage

Tags: fontspec

when I using xelatex to render this document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{green}

\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontspec}
\usepackage{tgcursor}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\setmainfont{lmroman10-regular.otf}
\setlength{\footskip}{149.60005pt}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}

\begin{document}
hello world!
\end{document}
```

shows error:

```
Option clash for package fontspec. \usepackage
```

why did this error happen? what should I do to fixed this issue?

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontspec}` doesn't make sense. Delete the line.

Comment: I have tried to delete `\usepackage[T1]{fontspec}
` but still could not fixed the issue, show error `Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}`.

Comment: your editor is not showing you error messages in a useful form, you should look at the error messages from tex in the log file which would have shown which options clashed and will show which command is undefined (`\@firstname` is undefined)

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1068/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately your editor's treatment of error messages makes them completely useless, ignore that and use the errors from tex in the log file.

The first error is

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package fontspec.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.8 \usepackage
               {tgcursor}
?
```

Delete `\usepackage[T1]{fontspec}`

You then get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@firstname 
                       {}~\@lastname {}
l.15 \begin{document}
                     
?
```

as no first name has been specified, so this runs without error in xelatex

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{green}

\usepackage{ctex}

\usepackage{tgcursor}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\setmainfont{lmroman10-regular.otf}
\setlength{\footskip}{149.60005pt}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}

\firstname{David}
\familyname{Carlisle}
\begin{document}
hello world!
\end{document}
```